# Group_Concat with left join is slowing down. I need all rows in left table as well

Tags: mysql, group-concat

```
SELECT applicant.id, applicant.firstname, applicant.lastname, applicant.state, applicant.mobile, applicant.lead_description, GROUP_CONCAT(note.note SEPARATOR ', ') as notes
FROM applicant LEFT JOIN
     note
     ON applicant.id = note.applicant_id
WHERE delete_type = 0 AND applicant.type = 0
GROUP BY applicant.id
ORDER BY applicant.id DESC
```

The result is too slow from 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.state, a.mobile, a.lead_description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(n.note SEPARATOR ', ') as notes
FROM applicant a LEFT JOIN
     note n
     ON a.id = n.applicant_id
WHERE delete_type = 0 AND a.type = 0
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

You should start with indexes.  I would recommend `applicant(type, id)` and `note(applicant_id)`.  And including `delete_type` in one of them (I don't know which table it comes from).

Second, this query may be faster using a correlated subquery.  This would look like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.state, a.mobile, a.lead_description,
       (select GROUP_CONCAT(n.note SEPARATOR ', ')
        from note n
        where a.id = n.applicant_id
       ) as notes
FROM applicant a
WHERE delete_type = 0 AND a.type = 0
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

The condition on `delete_type` either goes in the outer query or the subquery -- it is not clear which table this comes from.

This avoids the large `group by` on the external data, which can be a performance boost.

Comment: Thank you so so much. This query solved the timing issue

Comment: How can the subquery use the index, in this solution the index for the note table is not used when Explained by mysql.. I have an applicant_id index added..... any ideas?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanMohsen . . . Maybe if the table is really small, MySQL does not bother with the index.